# How can I send multiple XMLHttpRequests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I have a question about node js and the express framework.

I want to do the following in my server code:

- Call remote server with xmlhttprequest 1
- Process the response
- Call remote server with xmlhttprequest 2

This is a simplified version of my server code:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var contact = require('./routes/contact')
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
....
app.get('/', routes.index);   //<---currently this is handled in index.js, in function index.
```

index.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
 //xmlhttprequest 1    // <--- send xhr 1 
 //process data
 //xmlhttprequest 2    // <--- send xhr 2
};
```

I get the message `Cant send headers after they are sent`.  I read the express documentation and gleaned that this happens when we try to modify the header after the request has been sent. I also read something about middleware, and routing. But the documentation is not clear to me.

Can someone point out what the ideal way to do this would be?
I can work with links that have relevant information. I am new to express and node js.

Edit:
More details:

- The user is on the landing page of my website foo/.
- He enters some details, based on which i make the first
  xmlhttprequest.
- I process the data from API 1, use the processed data as input for
  API 2, which is again an    xmlhttprequest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send two different `XHR` requests, you'll need to define two different routes for it:

```
app.get('/XHR1', routes.xhr1);
app.get('/XHR2', routes.xhr2);
```

The reason you're getting `Can't send headers after they are sent` is because you're responding to the client (probably through something like `res.send(200)`, [full list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086621/1216976)) and then trying to respond to the client *again*.  You can only respond once per call.

Comment: But what if i want the two xhr's to be sent as part of the same URL, without routing the user to two different URLs on the server? For example: app.get('/', routes.xhr1and2)

Comment: You'll need to provide more code - I don't quite understand what you're asking.